# Oracle HR Schema. Selecting of max salary from Employees

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select city, max salary in the city and employee name whose salary is max from Oracle HR Schema.
I try to do below code, but city name repeats:

```
select l.city, e.last_name, e.salary from locations l 
inner join departments d on l.location_id = d.location_id
inner join employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
and e.salary = (select max(salary) from employees where department_id = d.department_id)
group by l.city, e.last_name, e.salary
order by e.salary;
```

What is wrong with my code?
I've attached result, which I need.[Correct SQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxa8M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function (which will return all employees with the maximum salary per city):

```sql
SELECT city,
       last_name,
       salary
FROM   (
  SELECT l.city,
         e.last_name,
         e.salary,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY l.location_id
           ORDER BY e.salary DESC
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   locations l
         INNER JOIN departments d
         ON l.location_id = d.location_id
         INNER JOIN employees e
         ON d.department_id = e.department_id
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

or aggregation with `KEEP` (which will only return one employee with the maximum salary and the maximum last name per location):

```sql
SELECT MAX(l.city) AS city,
       MAX(e.last_name) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY e.salary ) AS last_name,
       MAX(e.salary) AS salary
FROM   locations l
       INNER JOIN departments d
       ON l.location_id = d.location_id
       INNER JOIN employees e
       ON d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY
       l.location_id
```

> What is wrong with my code?

You are correlating on `department_id = d.department_id` and not on the location (or city name; however, don't aggregate on the city name as there could be two different locations with the same name).